# How to change out excel chart data with VB.Net

Tags: excel, vb.net, charts, range

I am exporting an excel spreadsheet with an app using vb.NET. The rows I want to show on the chart are rows 111, 31, and 6. Row 6 is the x-axis serial number and rows 111 and 31 are y axis values. The excel file has the column headers in column A and then data in the rest. When I use only 2 of the 3 rows everything is fine, for example 111 and 6 or 31 and 6. However, when I try and combine all 3 the data gets switched around where row 6 is no longer the x axis. Here is my code:

```
Excel work book example
Column A                        ColumnB  ......   ColumnN
Row6(Serial Number, x axis)     Data 1            DataN
Row31(Series 1 value, y ax      Data 1            DataN
Row111(Series 2 Value, y axis)  Data 1            DataN




            'Create chart
        Dim chartPage As excel.Chart
        Dim xlCharts As excel.ChartObjects
        Dim myChart As excel.ChartObject
        Dim chartRange As excel.Range

        xlCharts = xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects
        myChart = xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250)
        chartPage = myChart.Chart
        chartRange = xlWorkSheet.Range("111:111, 31:31, 6:6")
        chartPage.SetSourceData(Source:=chartRange)
        chartPage.ChartType = excel.XlChartType.xlLine
```

I would like to draw attention to the following line of code:

```
chartRange = xlWorkSheet.Range("111:111, 31:31, 6:6")
```

If I replace this line of code with either of the 2 following lines the code works properly:

```
chartRange = xlWorkSheet.Range("111:111, 6:6")
chartRange = xlWorkSheet.Range("31:31, 6:6")
```

However I want both the 111 and 31 rows to show up on the same chart.

Desired output are serial numbers along the x axis with numeric data on the y axis. 2 lines one that maps row 111 and the other that maps row 31

Current output is Serial number as the series and both the x and y axis are numeric

***IMPORTANT EDIT***
This code actually does work. I was only using 1 row to keep my build time down and it was messing up the exported excel sheet. However when I used a full compile with all the rows it started working. However, it only works when the 6:6 is at the end of the line.